# Lebanon - Visa on arrival requirements

Tags: hotels, visas-on-arrival, lebanon

My girlfriend is coming from Lithuania to Lebanon in a week, now I'm reading everywhere that Lithuanian citizens can get a "Visa on Arrival" while they are at the Lebanese Airport.

One of the requirements to get the visa is to give an address in Lebanon.
I've reserved a hotel in my name for 2 weeks then we will spend a week at my family's house before she travel back.

So my questions are:

1- Will it be a problem that the hotel reservation is in my name and not hers when she goes to the airport security? (I can edit the booking still if it will be a problem.)

2- Is she even able to say that she will spend 2 weeks in hotel then 1 week at my family's place? Or they won't like the answer?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I found what appears to be the [official documentation in English](http://www.general-security.gov.lb/en/posts/38), but it's quite confusing, possibly because it's been translated to English.

Comment: This is indeed confusing, more than it should be.. :D